# How to convert a CSV file to Parquet using C#

Tags: c#, parquet

I am new to C#, I want to convert a CSV file to Parquet format, I searched some sites but I am not getting the expected one. Is there anyway way to do in C#?

Comment: Are you searching for a library that does the job for you or are you searching for the specification of the file format to implement it yourself?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a library to work with C#

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @NetMage - mores the pity - the great separation of ways , way way back. Still miss the SO where you could ask for book or library recommendations etc.

Answer (score 2):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.Parquet/) - an open source library, you can convert CSV file to Parquet
easily.

Install Nuget package

> install-package ChoETL.Parquet

Sample code

> using ChoETL;

```
string csv = @"Id, Name
1, Tom
2, Mark";

using (var r = ChoCSVReader.LoadText(csv)
    .WithFirstLineHeader()
    .WithMaxScanRows(2)
    .QuoteAllFields()
    )
{
    using (var w = new ChoParquetWriter("*** Your Parquet file ***"))
    {
        w.Write(r);
    }
}
```

For more information, please visit codeproject article.