# CSV file to Parquet using C#

Tags: c#, csv, parquet

I am new to C#,
We have requirement to generate parquet files from csv.
Our file sizes up to 30gb, so performance is the matter while generating.

I do not get any help/suggestions from google to handle.

Can someone suggest or share solution please (Either console /Script task).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a csv file to parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124417/how-to-convert-a-csv-file-to-parquet)

Comment: requirement is to create C# console program, thanks

Comment: If you're programming in C# one assumes you know what NuGet packages are. Have you looked for a NuGet package that can read and write Parquet files?

Comment: Why is this tagged SQl Server? anyway I typed _C# Parquet Library_ into google and this was the top link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Parquet.Net It's inconcievable to me that you could not find this.

Comment: Does this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929842/how-to-convert-a-csv-file-to-parquet-using-c-sharp/62181950#62181950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Parquet.Net/4.1.1#readme-body-tab), which includes automatic serializer/deserializer from C# classes into parquet files that works by generating MSIL (bytecode) on the fly and is therefore super fast.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet, but do it via CLI tools and just call those from C# [aka "shell out"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/wait-shelled-app-finish#wait-indefinitely-for-the-shelled-application-to-finish).

- https://github.com/domoritz/arrow-tools

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 different solutions to this problem.

You can read the CSV files into a `IEnumerable<Dto>` and write the parquet file using either `Parquet.Net` or `ParquetSharp`.

The third solution is to use `DuckDB.Net` to craft a SQL statement to read the CSV directly into a Parquet file.

```
COPY (
    SELECT * 
    FROM read_csv('flights.csv', delim='|', header=True, columns={'FlightDate': 'DATE', 'UniqueCarrier': 'VARCHAR', 'OriginCityName': 'VARCHAR', 'DestCityName': 'VARCHAR'})
) TO 'test.parquet' (FORMAT 'parquet', COMPRESSION 'ZSTD', ROW_GROUP_SIZE 100000)
```

Using the `DuckDb.Net` `ADO.NET` connector.

Disclaimer: I am a contributor to the `DuckDB.Net` project.